# Paypal Standard not redirecting to mobile checkout when discount_amount posted

Tags: paypal

I'm testing the following on an `iPhone`. If I don't set a value for `discount_amount` and click `Buy` button I go to `Paypal mobile checkout` but when I add a value for `discount_amount` I get to standard web checkout. Does anyone know why and how to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="form1" class="panel">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@mysite.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.mysite.com/paypal_ipn">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mysite.com/success">
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mysite.com/">
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1708|288|18|app">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Sticker">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="STICKER">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="shipping" id="mc_shipping" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount" id="discount_amount" value="2">
  <fieldset>
    <label>Sticker Size:</label>
      <input id='on0' type='hidden' name='on0' value='Size'>
      <select name='os0' id='print_item'>
        <option value='42cm'>42cm - £27.99</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" id="option_tube0" value="small" />
      <input type="hidden" id="option_select0" name="option_select0" value="42cm" />
      <input type="hidden" item-price="27.99" id="option_amount0" name="option_amount0" value="27.99" />
      <br />
      <label>Quantity: </label>
      <select name="quantity" id="quantity">
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="" id="buy_now">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all of the variables that can be used are supported with the Mobile flow.  When you pass over a variable that is not supported, you will get directed through the regular web flow.  Below are some of the customizations that are not supported with the mobile flow.

1. Instant Update API
2. Buyer Supplied Price, Desc, Qty
3. Discounts
4. Payment Type: Auth, Order
5. Inventory Management

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Am I right in thinking there are no discount options if I was using PP Express rather than PP Standard? I'm thinking my only option is to reduce ItemAmount before Posting? Any other suggestions how to handle promo codes?

Comment: There are shipping discounts that can be applied, and you can apply any discount to the regular amount you are wanting to.  You would just pass over to PayPal the amount you are wanting to charge to.